# Read in and write csv

Tags: python, csv

I have the following code, which will read and write the some csv with some function performed on it. I skip the header row, but for some reason when it does the writerows it still reads the header and outputs a `"`, what's wrong?

```
  with open(back, 'rb') as input, open(file, 'wb') as output:
        writer = csv.writer(output)
        head = input.next().split(",")
        writer.writerow(head)
        writer.writerows(function(row) for row in csv.reader(input))
```

Example input:

```
HEADER
Line 1
Line 2
```

Output I'm getting:

```
HEADER 
"
Function(Line 1) 
Function(Line 2)
```

Comment: Can you show us the first few lines of the input, and the output it produces? And why not use a `csv.reader()` for the input as well?

Comment: You don't get a syntax error trying to use ```in``` as a variable?

Comment: @bj0 I renamed the vars to make it cleaner/easier to read.

Comment: Could it be that your file is partially in Windows format, i.e. it looks like `"HEADER\r\nLine 1\nLine 2\n"`?

Comment: Ah that's what it was, stupid mistake... Thanks @filmor.